# If I delete a discussion comment of mine, can I not undelete it myself?

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete, discussions-space

I did a test of what happens when I delete a discussion comment I create. I can edit it while it's deleted, but I can't figure out how to undelete it. Am I just UI-obtuse / UI-challenged? Or is there no way for me to do this?

Comment: Or perhaps you shouldn't be able to see deleted comments in the first place?

Comment: I think regular users are supposed to see their own deleted content, but I'm not sure if you're supposed to also be able to undelete or edit it. I see an undelete button on deleted replies as a Discussion Moderator.

Answer (score 2):

We don't yet have undeletion for post/reply authors. There's some additional provisions we still need to make, related to display of deleted Discussions content. An existing option for authors is to flag a deleted post/reply to request undeletion.